# Searching a string in a binary file in C

Tags: c, string, binaryfiles

In this code snippet I'm trying to add a string in a binary file. If the string already exists, I return error, otherwise I add it at EOF. I creataed two functions, void AddNewTeam(FILE* fp, char* newTeam), and int SearchTeam(FILE* fp, char* newTeam) as shown below, but that didn't work. Everytime I enter a string, it is added at EOF, even if is in the binary file.
I think the problem is the fread function, I tried to print the value returned by the fread but it is always 0. Can someone help me trying to understand what's wrong with this code and why it's not working?

```
void AddNewTeam(FILE* fp, const char* newTeam){
    int found;

    if((fp = fopen("File.dat", "rb")) == NULL){
        fp = fopen("File.dat", "ab");
        fclose(fp);
    }
            
    printf("\tEnter New Team: ");
    scanf("%s", newTeam);
            
    found = SearchTeam(fp, newTeam);
            
    if(found == 0){
        if((fp = fopen("File.dat", "ab"))){
            fwrite(newTeam, sizeof(newTeam), 1, fp);
            printf("\tThe following team has been successfully loaded\n");
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }else if(found == 1){
        printf("\tThis team already exists\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int SearchTeam(FILE* fp, const char* newTeam){
    char string[MAX][MAX_LENGTH];
    int counter, result, found = 0;
    if((fp = fopen("File.dat", "rb"))){
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        for(counter = 0; !feof(fp); counter++){
            if(fread(string[counter], sizeof(string[counter]), 1, fp) == 1){
                result = strcmp(newTeam, string[counter]);
                if(result == 0){
                    found = 1; break;
                }else if(result != 0){
                    found = 0;
                }       
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return found;
    }else if(fp == NULL){
        printf("\tError opening binary file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

> This is the main function and the function prototypes

```
int SearchTeam(FILE* fp, const char* newTeam);
void AddNewTeam(FILE* fp, const char* newTeam);

int main(void){
    FILE* fp;
    char newTeam[MAX_LENGTH];
    AddNewTeam(fp, newTeam);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an array in `searchTeam`? You can use the same string for each `fread()`.

Comment: `for(counter = 0; !feof(fp); counter++){` Dont use feof(). Never. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Consider opening a single `FILE*` and passing that as a parameter to any function that needs it. That way you can avoid *Hardcoded Filenames* which you use to open a stream 4 -different times within the two functions.

Comment: `const char* newTeam) .... scanf("%s", newTeam);` is a problem - writing to a `const`.  Post `AddNewTeam()` calling code.

Answer (score 3):

You're not appending to the file correctly. The search code expects each team name to be in a block of `MAX_LENGTH` bytes. But when you write, you do:

```
fwrite(newTeam, sizeof(newTeam), 1, fp);
```

`newTeam` is a pointer, not an array, so `sizeof` will be the size of a pointer, typically 4 or 8 bytes. You need to write `MAX_LENGTH` bytes so this will match the way you read from the file.

```
fwrite(newTeam, MAX_SIZE, 1, fp);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I've been struggling for hours on that code. Before using functions, I did the AddNewTeam and SearchTeam functions inside the main function and the code worked, why is that?

Comment: Because in the main function `newTeam` was an array, not a pointer. Just like in `searchTeam`.